# What is a S-X-X-XX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXX called in Windows security?

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, robocopy

I copied two trees, a source and a destination, that I copied with robocopy like this:

`robocopy /MIR C:\Windows\System32\tasks\ C:\temp\robocopyTasks\out\`

```
robocopy /E /Copy:S /IS /IT C:\Windows\System32\tasks\ C:\temp\robocopyTasks\out\
```

Then I compared the permission using icacls output the permissions on both, and the only difference seems to be that the original files contain a long string of characters which I've seen before; and I know it represents a user or a group in the system but I don't remember what it is called.  The strings look like this:

```
S-X-X-XX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXXX
```

They can be matched with this regex in VIM:

```
/S-\d-\d-\d\{2\}-\d\{10\}-\d\{10\}\-\d\{9\}\-\d\{4\}/
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong that is the SID (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's a SID, or [Security Identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If it's showing the string rather than a "friendly name," it sounds like the new server doesn't recognize the account.

Comment: I'm making the copies on the same machine.  (going to update my post)

Comment: Interesting.  Well, for some reason, it's confused.  (Network hiccup?)

Comment: I'd actually like to do the same thing on a Windows 2003 server; I'm testing it on my Windows 7 machine first; which is why I'm using the older syntax instead of `/SECFIX`

Comment: I updated my post to include my robocopy command.

Comment: I've seen that before at my previous job; even though properly authenticated, for some reason it used the SIDs instead of the AD names for displaying permissions.  Not sure if it's a particular permission setup or something weird with the AD server.

Comment: This happens when you create a new local Administrator account, and copy files belonging to another local Administrator account.  The new account cannot access files belonging to the old account even though both accounts are Administrator

Comment: If you disable UAC this behavior goes away.